# How to find which author and committer has done more commits to a project using git log?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, git-log

I have been browsing [Git Basics - Viewing the Commit History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)  as well as  [Git Tools - Searching](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Searching) and while most of the ways seem straight-forward I have been trying to figure out if there was a way to figure out the author who has done the most commits or/and the committers who has done most of the commits in a porject.

I am sure there would be some ways like -

1. Find the author who has done the most commits in a project.
2. find the authors who have done the most commits in a descending manner.
3. Find committers who have done the most commits in a project

and things like that. It could make for some interesting analysis of a project's state per se.

Do people have any idea what could be done in the above instance?

I am on Debian buster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git log --pretty=format:%aN | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

[`git log --pretty=format:%aN` outputs just the author name](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) for every commit. [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) collects all the repeated names together, then [`uniq -c` turns each run of equal lines into the number of repetitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) and the value, before `sort`ing numerically. You can take the last line (`tail -n 1`) to find the most prolific, reverse the sort (`sort -nr`) for descending, or whatever other processing you like.

Answer (score 5):

There is a Git command specifically made for this purpose.

```
git shortlog --numbered --summary
```

or simply:

```
git shortlog -ns
```

See the manpage `git-shortlog(1)` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own tool to parse the git log, or you could use a tool such as [GitStats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/) which will produce a report listing, amongst other things, the top committers; see for example [this old report on the Linux kernel](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/linux-2.6/authors.html).

There are also services which will add analytics to projects; see for example [Bitergia](https://bitergia.com/), which produces [this sort of Kibana front-end](https://opendaylight.biterg.io/app/kibana).